# Performance of pixel transformation using clojure and quil

Tags: clojure, quil

Let's assume I'd like to wright an ocr algorithm. Therefore I want to create a binary image. Using clojure and quil I came up with:

```
(defn setup []

  (load-pixels)

  (let [pxls (pixels)
             ]
    (letfn [(pxl-over-threshold? [idx] (if (> (red (aget pxls idx)) 128) true false))
            ]
           (time (dotimes [idx 25500] (aset pxls idx (color (rem idx 255)))))

           (time (dotimes [idx 25500] (if (pxl-over-threshold? idx)
                                          (aset pxls idx (color 255))
                                          (aset pxls idx (color 0)))))))
  (update-pixels))

(defn draw [])

(defsketch example
  :title "image demo"
  :setup setup
  :draw draw
  :size [255 100]
  :renderer :p2d)

;"Elapsed time: 1570.58932 msecs"
;"Elapsed time: 2781.334345 msecs"
```

The code generates a grayscale and afterwards iterates over all pixels to set them black or white. It performs the requested behavior, but takes about 4.3 sec to get there (1.3 dual core). I don't have a reference to put the 4.3 sec in context. But thinking of processing a larger image, this must become incredibly slow.

Am I doing something terribly wrong or is there a way to fasten up things? Is the combination of clojure and quil even capable of doing pixel transformations faster or should I choose a different language/environment?

Please also let me know if I'm doing something weird in the code. I'm still new to clojure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timings you've taken aren't particularly meaningful because the code isn't warm yet. You need to "warm up" the code so that the JVM will JIT-compile it, and that's when you should start seeing good speed. You should look at [*How to benchmark functions in Clojure?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041299/how-to-benchmark-functions-in-clojure) (You should use [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium).)

As for your code, you're using arrays, so that should give you good performance. Style-wise, the two hanging `]` you have are really weird. Maybe that's just a formatting error? It's usually good to eliminate as much duplicate code as possible, so I'd also change this

```
(if (pxl-over-threshold? idx)
  (aset pxls idx (color 255))
  (aset pxls idx (color 0)))
```

to this

```
(aset pxls idx (color (if (pxl-over-threshold? idx) 255 0)))
```

If you feel looks too confusing/complex (I'm kind of right on the edge as to whether I'd consider that too hard to read or not), you could alternatively write it either of these ways instead:

```
(let [c (if (pxl-over-threshold? idx) 255 0)]
  (aset pxls idx (color c)))

(->> (if (pxl-over-threshold? idx) 255 0) color (aset pxls idx))
```