# Microbenchmark Clojure functions

Tags: clojure, benchmarking

#### Question

How fast are small Clojure functions like `assoc`?  I suspect that `assoc` operates in the 100ns to 3us range, which makes it difficult to time.

#### Using `time`

```
user=> (def d {1 1, 2 2})
#'user/d
user=> (time (assoc d 3 3))
"Elapsed time: 0.04989 msecs"
{1 1, 2 2, 3 3}
```

There is clearly a lot of overhead there so I don't trust this benchmark.  Friends pointed me to [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) which handles a lot of the pain of benchmarking (multiple evaluations, warming up the JVM, GC see [How to benchmark functions in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041299/how-to-benchmark-functions-in-clojure)).

#### Using `Criterium`

Sadly, on such a small benchmark even Criterium seems to fail

```
user=> (use 'criterium.core)
nil
user=> (def d {1 1 2 2})
#'user/d
user=> (bench (assoc d 3 3))
WARNING: JVM argument TieredStopAtLevel=1 is active, and may lead to unexpected results as JIT C2 compiler may not be active. See http://www.slideshare.net/CharlesNutter/javaone-2012-jvm-jit-for-dummies.
WARNING: Final GC required 1.694448681330372 % of runtime
Evaluation count : 218293620 in 60 samples of 3638227 calls.
             Execution time mean : -15.677491 ns
    Execution time std-deviation : 6.093770 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : -20.504699 ns ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 1.430632 ns (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 123.496848 ns
```

Just in case you missed it, this operation takes -15ns on average.  I know that Clojure is pretty magical, but negative runtimes seem a bit too good to be true.

#### Repeat the Question

So really, how long does an `assoc` take?  How can I benchmark micro operations in Clojure?

Comment: Just curious, what part of application do you want to improve the performance of?

Comment: I don't think there is an direct answer. You may want to watch Zach Tellmans talk "Predictably fast Clojure" from this years Clojure talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQwQXVM6oiY

Comment: @AlbusShin at the moment I'm actually genuinely interested in the performance of `assoc`.  I'm interested in hashmap performance under structural sharing vs copy-and-edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just wrap it in a loop and renormalize?

On my hardware,

```
(bench (dotimes [_ 1000] (assoc d 3 3)))
```

yields a mean execution time of roughly 1000x that of

```
(bench (assoc d 3 3))
```

namely, about 100 µs in the first case, and 100 ns in the second.  If your single-`assoc` is "in the noise" for Criterium, you could try wrapping it in the same way and get pretty close to the "intrinsic" value.  (`(dotimes [_ 1000] 1)` clocks in at .59 µs, so the extra overhead imposed by the loop itself is comparatively small.)

Comment: Any danger that this takes advantage of cached results?  Or is each `assoc` call doing equivalent work to the first?

Comment: From the Clojure standpoint, you'd have to memoize to get caching, I think.  Of course the hardware's use of its cache is another story, as are JVM particulars.  But the above test tells a pretty simple tale.

Answer (score 5):

Criterium tries to net out the overhead due to its own measurement. This can result in negative results for fast functions. See the [Measurement Overhead Estimation](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium#measurement-overhead-estimation) section of the readme. Your overhead is suspiciously high. You might run `(estimatated-overhead!)` *[sic]* a few times to sample for a more accurate overhead figure.

Answer (score 4):

Andy Fingerhut has maintained some of these for a while.

- Home - http://jafingerhut.github.io/clojure-benchmarks-results/Clojure-benchmarks.html
- Results - http://jafingerhut.github.io/clojure-benchmarks-results/Clojure-expression-benchmark-graphs.html

ClojureScript:

- Project - https://github.com/netguy204/cljs-bench
- Results - http://www.50ply.com/cljs-bench/