# Real world Clojure performance tuning tips?

Tags: clojure

I am seeing some serious slowdowns in "some" parts of a Clojure application. Does anyone have any real world tips as to how they have done performance tuning on a clojure application?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

My personal tips:

- **Check your algorithm first** - are you incurring O(n^2) cost when it really should be O(n.log n)? If you've picked a bad algorithm, the rest of tuning is a waste of time.

  - Be aware of common "gotchas" like the O(n) cost of traversing a list / sequence.
  - Take advantage of nice features in Clojure, like the O(1) cost of copying a large persistent data structure or the O(log32 n) cost of map/set/vector accesses.
- Choose among Clojure's core constructs wisely:

  - An **atom** is great when you need some mutable data, e.g. updating some data in a loop
  - If you are going to traverse some data in sequence, use a **list** rather than a vector or map since this will avoid creating temporary objects while traversing the sequence.
  - Use **deftype/defrecord/defprotocol** where appropriate. These are heavily optimised, and in particular should be preferred to defstruct/multimethods as of Clojure 1.2 onwards.
- Take advantage of Clojure's concurrency capabilities:

  - **pmap** and **future** are both relatively easy ways to take advantage of multiple cores when you are doing a number of independent computations at the same time.
  - Remember that because of Clojure's **immutable persistent data structures**, making and working on multiple copies of data is very inexpensive. You also don't have to worry about locking when taking snapshots.....
- If you are interfacing with Java code, use "(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)" and **eliminate *every* reflection warning**. Reflection is one of the most expensive operations, and will really slow your application down if done repeatedly.
- If you still need more performance, identify the most performance critical parts of your code (e.g. the 5% of lines where the application spends 90%+ of CPU time), analyse this section in detail and judiciously apply the following rules:

  - **Avoid laziness**. Laziness is a great feature but comes with some additional overhead. Be aware that many of Clojure's common sequence / list functions are lazy (e.g. for, map, partition). loop/recur, dotimes and reduce are your non-lazy friends.
  - Use **primitive hints** and **unchecked arithmetic** to make arithmetic / numerical code faster. Primitives are *much* faster than Clojure's default BigInteger arithmetic.
  - **Minimise memory allocations** - try to avoid creating too much unnecessary intermediate data (vectors, lists, maps, non-primitive numbers etc.). All allocations impose a small amount of extra overhead, and also result in more/longer GC pauses over time (this is likely to be a bigger concern if you are writing a game / soft realtime app.).
  - **(Ab)use Java arrays** - not really idiomatic in Clojure, but aget / aset / areduce and friends are very fast (they benefit from a lot of JVM optimisations!!). (Ab)use primitive arrays for extra bonus points.
  - **Use macros** - to generate ugly-but-fast code at compile time where possible

Doing all the above should get pretty good performance out of Clojure code - with careful tuning I've usually been able to get reasonably near to pure Java performance, which is pretty impressive for a dynamic language!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [JVisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/index.html) to do profiling of Clojure code (see [JVisualVM and Clojure](http://www.fatvat.co.uk/2009/05/jvisualvm-and-clojure.html) for an example).  This should at least point you in the right direction of the slow code.

Comment: Have you got any tips on how to use VisualVM with Clojure, as I tried it but the names of the classes were pretty meaningless to me?

Comment: When I last looked (some time ago), I found the method names pretty readable - maybe something has changed.

Comment: I guess the problem I have is that the class names are not the same as the clojure names unless you use records

Answer (score 5):

This question covers profiling with Clojure: [Profiling tool for Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974916/profiling-tool-for-clojure)

I'm sure you'll find some good tips there.

Then straight from the horse's mouth: http://clojure.org/getting_started#Getting%20Started-Profiling

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I guess there are no Clojure specific tools yet, but I could always roll my own according to those links