# profiling in clojure (for large code)

Tags: clojure, profiling, profile

Search on Google shows some results for clojure profiling. [Profiling tool for Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974916/profiling-tool-for-clojure)
This link shows that profiling will blow up if large code is there.  http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/profile-api.html. Is there any stable profiling tool for clojure? 
I need to profile huge library made in clojure with some clojure functions of upto 400 lines.

Answer (score 5):

We've used [YourKit](http://yourkit.com/) successfully.  No special steps - just set it up like any other JVM app.  Of course, interpreting the results is a bit of an art form.  You can play with the filters to sometimes get it to ignore clojure core.

I found it useful to set it up on a swank server which let me profile parts of the app in the REPL (and turn things on and off between runs).

Comment: I have installed it. While profiling with Eclipse, its asking for applet. whats should be done?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I haven't used it from Eclipse.  You want to set up your Clojure app (or repl) using J2SE profiling - several options doc'ed here: http://yourkit.com/docs/10/help/profiling_j2se.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Which do you need to do - profile? or speed up the code?
If the latter, check out [random pausing](http://sourceforge.net/projects/randompausedemo/).

Comment: How is this applicable to Clojure?